# Is there a lighter version of the firebase admin SDK that only includes the auth package for Go?

Tags: firebase, go, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have the whole `firebase.google.com/go/v4` library as a dependency just to be able to do the following:

```
client *auth.Client
client.VerifyIDToken(ctx, bearerToken)
```

Is there a lighter version of the firebase library that only includes the auth package? Or better yet, that just does firebase ID token validation.

Comment: Im pretty sure that there is no such package. Why do you need it? You could use this lib, but ignore unnessecary functionality?

Comment: I don't really NEED it. But before adding it, my builds were almost instantaneous and my CI pipeline as well. Now my CI pipeline takes like 40s longer for each step which is not something to die about but it feels really unnecessary.

Comment: Why is your CI taking so much longer? Is it due to downloading the SDK every time? Maybe a local cache could help?

Comment: Yes I think it downloads it every time. I will take a look on how to configure caching for CircleCI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one version of the Firebase Admin SDK for Go, and it contains clients for all Firebase features the SDK supports. Unlike with the client-side SDKs, there are no separate Admin SDKs for individual Firebase features.

If you don't want to use the Admin SDK for Go, you can:

- write your code to directly talk against the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth).
- take the [code of the SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-go) and see if you can build a stripped down version that only includes what you need.

Comment: Hmm I might take a look at option 2. Thanks